# Websphere. Get session from entitymanager

Tags: hibernate, jpa, websphere

How can I get hibernate session from EntityManager at Websphere?

Tried:

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
```

Got:

```
[5/22/15 14:24:01:049 MSK] 00000099 SystemErr     R <openjpa-2.2.3-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1642995 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: EntityManager can not be unwrapped to an instance of "interface org.hibernate.Session".
FailedObject: com.ibm.ws.persistence.EntityManagerImpl@e14c33cf
```

Tryed also:

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
Session session = session = (Session) em.getDelegate();
```

Got:

```
[5/22/15 13:23:45:930 MSK] 00000098 SystemErr     R java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.ws.persistence.EntityManagerImpl incompatible with org.hibernate.Session
```

Comment: You are using some kind of openJPA implementation as far as google toldme. So if you wana use Hibernate you will probably have to change the implementation in some way for your Application Server. Beside that. For what do you need the Session?

Comment: @mh-dev Thanks! Now trying change JPA implementation to Hibernate. Need session for use JDBC-queries